# Adding variable in single triple quotes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mixpanel

This might be the simplest question, I have tried the solution for triple double-quotes.

But as per Mixpanel documentation, they are passing single triple quotes like below.

I have to pass my date variable here.

```
fromdate = '2022-03-12'
todate = '2022-03-12'

query1 = '''function main() {
return Events({
  from_date: fromdate,
  to_date:   todate,
  event_selectors:[
  {'event':'Event name'}
  ]
})
 }'''


print(query1)
```

3

Comment: What's wrong with string concatenation?

Comment: what is wrong is that there are 3 other straightforward ways of doing string interpolation in Python syntax, each more confortable for reading and writting than string concatenation.

Comment: @jsbueno ... which are quite easy to find.

Comment: Plus the other methods using modules for code generation

Comment: Code should not be generated using string interpolation if you can at all avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)

```
fromdate = '2022-03-12'
todate = '2022-03-12'

query1 = f'''function main() {{
  return Events({{
    from_date: {fromdate},
    to_date:   {todate},
    event_selectors:[
      {{'event':'Event name'}}
    ]
  }})
}}'''
```

Do notice that you need to escape the curly braces as `{{` and `}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "f" prefixed strings to be able to interpolate Python expressions in another string.

What you want is probably:

```
fromdate = '2022-03-12'
todate = '2022-03-12'

query1 = f'''function main() {{
return Events({{
  from_date: {fromdate},
  to_date:   {todate},
  event_selectors:[
  {{'event':'Event name'}}
  ]
}})
 }}'''


print(query1)

--
Note that the original ocurrences of `{}` have to be doubled so that they are escaped.
```